# TCP - Sending message then disconnecting

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

Let's assume I am connected to someone using a System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient. I send a message to them, then I immediately call TcpClient.Close(); Is the other client guaranteed to get the message? Also, is this true/false in most TCP implementations?

Comment: In short - no, it's not guaranteed (except some specific conditions/usage)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why TCP over UDP if you're looking to have a fire & forget type message?

Comment: @ColinM - I'm making a chat application and was trying to find the best way to "kick" someone. I was hoping the server could send a message that the person has been kicked by X for reason Y, then immediately close the connection and disconnect them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vlad's comment is correct - the delivery is not guaranteed.

Assume the TCP connection with a peer is established. The send operation just copy the data to the network stack in the operating system and it is OS responsibility to send it. The you call operation close. OS does not stop sending the previous data. OS postpone the socket close till data is sent. It is transparent from the application point of view.

But something wrong may happen. The peer may crash, network may have an outage or whatever. Although the OS tries to retransmit data if TCP ACK is not received the retrasmission may fail again and again till OS gives up. This general mechanism is the same in all OS implementing TCP protocol.

If you need guaranteed delivery then you must implement an application level mechanism to acknowledge received data.